# I cannot root or access developer options

Tags: rooting, samsung, developer-options

My Samsung Galaxy Tab A (model number SM-P550 if you want to know the specs, Android version 6.0.1) will not allow me to "unhide" or "unlock" my developer options no matter how many times i tap the build number. On another note i am unable to root my device and because i do not currently own a pc and i have tried every mobile rooting technique i could find, thank you for adressing this issue.
Edit - so i finnally figured it out, this device has many "accounts" and you can only access thing like the dev options on the "owner" but i was using "guest" but i still cannot root but im sure i will figure it out eventually, thank all of you for your suggestions and help!

Comment: What does "will not allow me to access" mean? What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: Did you try tapping on the build number 10 times in the "About Device" section? That enables the developer options.

Comment: What i mean by access is no matter how many times i tap the build number and no matter what else i do i cannot "unlock" or "access" the developer options.

Comment: Look like you're running a quite old AOS version (6.0.1) from early 2016, and unfortunately Samsung are notorious for buggy firmwares. I'd recommend you to look for a different updated firmware and try that. Or if recently bought, take it back to your shop. As WillW said, all shop bought Androids should have this possibility, unless you got a stolen device that have been blocked somehow.

Comment: Could you [edit] your post to include all the relevant information? If people have to watch a video to understand what your problem is, they're much less likely to try to help. It also makes it less likely that your question will come up in search results.

Comment: @not2qubit no infact its roughly 6 months old so i cannot take it back to the store where i bought it, also i dont even remember where that is. But i think this firmare idea sounds pretty good but i dont know how to do that.

Comment: @Gokul NC - im sorry i dont understand whet you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Every Android should be able to get developer options.  Wrichik Basu's comment says how to show developer options. However OEM Unlocking (first step to root) is disabled on basically all Samsung phones.

Comment: Yes i know how to do it but it wont work, nothing i do works.

Comment: hymm, interesting. Try deleting cache for settings as per the later portion of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=94qQbr_J9cw

Comment: next resort is update to android nougat

Comment: I tried clearing the data of the setting app as the video said but the developer options still will not "unlock" no matter how many times i tap the build number.

Comment: -WillW- how do i do that?

Comment: try https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00050677/. Under the update via computer section

Comment: if that doesnt work you can use Odin: https://forum.xda-developers.com/tab-4/general/guide-how-to-restore-stock-firmware-t2979006

Comment: It says you need the usb debugging option enabled but its in the developer options witch i cannot access.

Comment: if you want to install a stock rom via odin, you dont need usb debugging to be on, just boot into odin/download mode and flash a stock rom, then do whatever you need.

Comment: While i do know alot about mobile devices were getting into uncharted territory for me so i would need a step by step tutorial if im going to do this.

Comment: thats what the XDA guide is doing. We are essentially wiping your android  and reinstalling the newest from samsung

Comment: Okay but i also dont know anything about backing up my device without a pc.

Comment: samsung switch can back up using a PC, I dont think you need USB debugging enabled for that

Comment: Unfortunately i dont own a PC.

Answer (score 0):

Can you access recovery if yes then click apply update via adb...then do a 
Fastboot into a custom adb enabled recovery like twrp or cwm

```
$ fastboot boot /tmp/cwm.zip
```

Or

```
$fastboot flash recover twrp.img
```

After booting into recovery you can have your ADB enable also then you can root your device

Comment: But adb  requires USB debugging mode enabled, which is in the dev options. Anyways he is at a dead end.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan but unfortunately i dont really understand what most of that means.

Comment: Samsung devices have no fastboot.

Comment: I do not know how to access recovery mode, but im sure i can figure it out.